# How do I turn on the login startup sound theme?

Tags: sound, sound-theme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable the old Africa Savana sound at the boot of Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204578/how-can-i-enable-the-old-africa-savana-sound-at-the-boot-of-ubuntu-12-04)

I remember old releases of Ubuntu, when started you got these African drums initiating your session.
Now, (12.04 or 12.10) I do not hear them any more. So, here is my naive question: Is there a way to turn them on?

Answer (score 1):

This help was given to me a few hours ago by mtashev and it worked:

Click Startup Applications in the system menu at the top right of your computer.

Click ADD, name it > GNOME Login Sound  In the command field type >  /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login sound"

Make sure the checkbox is checked.

Reboot

Enjoy

Comment: How can  a question asked 2 days ago, be a duplicate of a question asked 6 hours ago? It should be the other way!

Anyway, thank you Baltazar for indicating em the way to accomplish my target. Of course I also thank mtashev for his reply.