# How can I enable the old African Savanna sound on boot?

Tags: sound

Hi I would like very much to enable the sound when I start Ubuntu with the old African Savanna sound that Ubuntu had in older versions . Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Africa Savana Sound?? Cool name!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click Startup Applications in the system menu at the top right of your computer.

Click ADD, name it > GNOME Login Sound

In the command field type >

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login sound"
```

Make sure the checkbox is checked.

Logout and login.

Enjoy